# Java - multiple signature using generic?

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface Factory<T>
{
    T create();
}

public interface Factory<T,P>
{
    T create(P... data);
}
```

Is there a way to define those interface so i can use the name `Factory` for both type, or do I have to use `FactoryWithParam`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't join the two interfaces into one?

```
public interface Factory<T,P>
{
    T create();
    T create(P... data);
}
```

But if you can't then there's no way you can have two different interfaces with the same name in the same package. You can put them in different packages but I'd strongly advise against it, it will confuse the hell out of whoever will maintain the code.

Answer (score 1):

No, because of how generics work. To maintain backward compatibility, there is no difference in the compiled bytecode for generified classes - they enforce compile-time checking only! This would mean you would have two classes with the same name, which is not allowed (within the same package).

Answer (score 0):

You can, but only if you place these two interfaces in two different packages.